# How to check if SQL Server 2012 Express edition is installed or not in wix toolset?

Tags: wix, sql-server-2012-express

How to check if SQL Server 2012 Express edition is installed or not in Wix toolset installation?

```
<Property Id="SQLSERVER">
    <RegistrySearch Id="SQLServer" Root="HKLM" 
                    Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS" 
                    Win64="yes" Type="raw" Name="InstalledInstances"/>
</Property>

<Condition Message="You don't have SQL Server installed.">
  <![CDATA[SQLSERVER >< SQLEXPRESS]]>
</Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparison operator should be <> and not >< .

```
<![CDATA[SQLSERVER <> "SQLEXPRESS"]]>
```

You can check [expression-syntax](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/) from wix site.